# Locale Middleware and View Composer Service Provider

Tags: laravel, middleware, service-provider

I'm developing a multi language website with Laravel 5.4 and I'm having trouble setting the middleware and the service provider logic. I already realized that servide provider is executed before the middleware. The problem is that I set the application locale on the middleware. On other hand, I have a service provider to feed localized data into the application's nav bar and footer. My problem is that by the time the service provider is executed, it doesn't know what the real locale is.

This is my handle function on Locale middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $locales_arr = Language::localesArr();

    // if there isn't a slug on URL
    if(!session()->has('app.locale') && $request->segment(1) === null)
    {
        // browser preference
        $client_locale = substr(\Request::server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

        // if it is a valid locale
        if(in_array($client_locale, $locales_arr))
        {
            $locale = $client_locale;
        }
        else {
            $locale = config('app.fallback_locale');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $locale = in_array($request->segment(1), $locales_arr) ? $request->segment(1) : config('app.fallback_locale');
    }

    // set locale prefix
    $locale_prefix = ($locale != config('app.fallback_locale')) ? $locale : '';

    // set locale
    app()->setLocale($locale);

    config(['app.locale_prefix' => $locale_prefix]);
    session(['app.locale' => $locale]);
    session()->save();

    setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale . "_" . strtoupper($locale));

    return $next($request);
}
```

And this is my boot function on ViewComposerServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    /* this doesn't work properly!!! */
    dump(app()->getLocale());
}
```

Can someone please help? I'm really stuck on this issue...

Comment: put the service provider logic in the middleware. Keep in mind that the View is the last one to be loaded and rendered, cause is part of the response. And please post some code, its difficult to answer a so broad question

Comment: Hi dparoli. I followed your suggestion and it worked! Thks for your help!